# ggplot create dynamic multi KPIs donut in one chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts, powerbi, donut-chart

I have a projects list with dynamic KPIs per project, each KPI has (a value and target)

I am receiving the dataset in the below format, I am trying to drow one chart for kpi for one project :

```
dataset <- data.frame(
  value = c(3,5,200.....), 
  Target = c(10,20,250.....), 
  KPI = c("a","b","c","d",....)
)
```

Is there any way to achieve multi-donut KPIs using ggplot!! (or even a pie chart) to look similar to the below image!

[image]

Comment: What do you want to show in your donut pies, you have several values in your dataset

Comment: @YacineHajji Thank you for your response!
I want to show multiple donuts in one chart, each donut should display one KPI, so each donut should display
 1. value
 2. target - value 
so I can get in every chart how much is remaining from this API like the attached picture .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dataset %>%
  mutate(perc = value/Target) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = 3, y = perc)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = 0, ymax = 1), size = 4, color = "#caeee3") +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = 0, ymax = perc), size = 4, color = "#01b8aa") +
  geom_text(aes(x = 1.5, y = 0, label = scales::percent(perc)), size = 6) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 0, y = 0, label = KPI), size = 8, color = 'gray80') +
  coord_polar(theta = 'y') +
  theme_void() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 4), expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  facet_wrap(.~KPI) +
  theme(strip.text = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: As you use it the second time I have to check out `geom_linerange` too as an alternative for `geom_col` or `geom_rect`.

Comment: Nice graph, more straight forward

Comment: @ghrah I only commented. It was Allan who answered and provided the nice solution. :D

Comment: @stefan I changed it, Thank you too any way  : D

Answer (score 2):

Proposition

```
##### Libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

##### Data management
# KPI a
dataset_a <- data.frame(count=c(3, 7),
                        KPI=c("a", "a"),
                        category=c("value", "nonReached"))
dataset_a$fraction <- prop.table(dataset_a$count)
dataset_a$ymax <- cumsum(dataset_a$fraction)
dataset_a$ymin <- c(0, head(dataset_a$ymax, n=-1))
dataset_a$labelPosition <- (dataset_a$ymax + dataset_a$ymin) / 2
dataset_a$label <- paste0(dataset_a$category, "\n value: ", dataset_a$count)
# KPI b
dataset_b <- data.frame(count=c(5, 15),
                        KPI=c("b", "b"),
                        category=c("value", "nonReached"))
dataset_b$fraction <- prop.table(dataset_b$count)
dataset_b$ymax <- cumsum(dataset_b$fraction)
dataset_b$ymin <- c(0, head(dataset_b$ymax, n=-1))
dataset_b$labelPosition <- (dataset_b$ymax + dataset_b$ymin) / 2
dataset_b$label <- paste0(dataset_b$category, "\n value: ", dataset_b$count)
# KPI c
dataset_c <- data.frame(count=c(200, 50),
                        KPI=c("c", "c"),
                        category=c("value", "nonReached"))
dataset_c$fraction <- prop.table(dataset_c$count)
dataset_c$ymax <- cumsum(dataset_c$fraction)
dataset_c$ymin <- c(0, head(dataset_c$ymax, n=-1))
dataset_c$labelPosition <- (dataset_c$ymax + dataset_c$ymin) / 2
dataset_c$label <- paste0(dataset_c$category, "\n value: ", dataset_c$count)

##### The plots
pie_a <- ggplot(dataset_a, aes(ymax=ymax, ymin=ymin, xmax=4, xmin=3, fill=category)) + 
  geom_rect() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#2bbd97", "#64f0cb")) + 
  coord_polar(theta="y") + 
  xlim(c(-1, 4)) + 
  theme_void() + 
  theme(legend.position = "none") + 
  geom_text(x=0.5, y=2, label=paste(round(subset(dataset_a, category=="value")$fraction, 2)*100, "%", sep=""), size=9) + 
  geom_text(x=-1.5, y=2, label=paste("KPI a"), size=6, color="#a4a4a4")
pie_b <- ggplot(dataset_b, aes(ymax=ymax, ymin=ymin, xmax=4, xmin=3, fill=category)) + 
  geom_rect() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#2bbd97", "#64f0cb")) + 
  coord_polar(theta="y") + 
  xlim(c(-1, 4)) + 
  theme_void() + 
  theme(legend.position = "none") + 
  geom_text(x=0.5, y=2, label=paste(round(subset(dataset_b, category=="value")$fraction, 2)*100, "%", sep=""), size=9) + 
  geom_text(x=-1.5, y=2, label=paste("KPI b"), size=6, color="#a4a4a4")
pie_c <- ggplot(dataset_c, aes(ymax=ymax, ymin=ymin, xmax=4, xmin=3, fill=category)) + 
  geom_rect() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#2bbd97", "#64f0cb")) + 
  coord_polar(theta="y") + 
  xlim(c(-1, 4)) + 
  theme_void() + 
  theme(legend.position = "none") + 
  geom_text(x=0.5, y=2, label=paste(round(subset(dataset_c, category=="value")$fraction, 2)*100, "%", sep=""), size=9) + 
  geom_text(x=-1.5, y=2, label=paste("KPI c"), size=6, color="#a4a4a4")

##### Display plots
ggarrange(pie_a, 
          pie_b, 
          pie_c, 
          nrow=1, ncol=3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the KPIs is not fixed number 3, they are dynamic and the total could be change , Thanks again

Comment: Then you need to show in detail what you expect to be dynamic in these graphs

Comment: Yes, it was not clear I updated the Question. Thank you